# A really strange bug for base64 decoding with openssl

Tags: c, debugging, openssl, base64

I use this code to do the base64 decoding work, but a strange bug occurs. the short code like this:

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/buffer.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
        char *str = "aGVsbG8=";
        char *xa_en = NULL;
        int xa_en_len = 0;
        int q=1, sid=1;

        printf("q:%d; sid:%d;\n", q, sid);
        Base64Decode(str, &xa_en, &xa_en_len);

        printf("q:%d; sid:%d; xa_en:%s;\n", q, sid, xa_en);
}

size_t calcDecodeLength(const char* b64input) { //Calculates the length of a decoded string
        size_t len = strlen(b64input),
                padding = 0;

        if (b64input[len-1] == '=' && b64input[len-2] == '=') //last two chars are =
                padding = 2;
        else if (b64input[len-1] == '=') //last char is =
                padding = 1;

        return (size_t)len*0.75 - padding;
}

int Base64Decode(char* b64message, uint8_t** buffer, size_t* length) { //Decodes a base64 encoded string
        BIO *bio, *b64;

        int decodeLen = calcDecodeLength(b64message);
        *buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(decodeLen);

        bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(b64message, -1);
        b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
        bio = BIO_push(b64, bio);

        BIO_set_flags(bio, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL); //Do not use newlines to flush buffer
        *length = BIO_read(bio, *buffer, strlen(b64message));
        BIO_free_all(bio);

        return (0); //success
}
```

compile this code with :

```
gcc -g -o Base64 Base64.c  -lssl -lcrypto
```

and run with:

```
./Base64
```

**Expected Output**

q:1; sid:1;
q:1; sid:1; xa_en:hello;

**Arrived Output**

q:1; sid:1;
q:0; sid:1; xa_en:hello;

**My question**

How can this happen? how can the `Base64Decode` function influence the value of q?

I guess it should be some buffer overflow bug but can not figure out. Is this a bug for openssl or what?
Someone help me please, thanks.

Comment: Have you compiled with full warnings? Does Base64Decode() really take 3 arguments? Oops, never mind, didn't scroll down and see your own Base64Decode().

Comment: Is it not necessary to null-terminate the buffer after the BIO_read()? If so, using calloc() instead of malloc() would fix the problem...

Comment: Could you #include assert.h and put a `assert(sizeof(size_t) <= sizeof(int))` somewhere (since your code does rely on that assumption).

Comment: Thank you, Ron, you are right, it is caused by wrong usage of size_t, the size of size_t is larger than size of int, after I replace size_t with int, everything is correct now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If sizeof(size_t) is bigger than sizeof(int), that would potentially explain the behavior, since you would be overwriting part of the stack when you assign to `*length`. Your compiler should have been able to give you a warning on the problem.

Comment: You are definitely right! I print out the sizeof(size_t), the result is 8 bytes, obviously bigger than the sizeof(int), which is 4 bytes. You are genius! Thank you!